# How can I insert a text in a determined position of an editor frame using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that users can create some documents based on a model selected previously, when this page opens a Primefaces p:editor component is filled with the model selected so that users are able to do any change they need.

Now they asked for a function that would import some data from database into the document because they spend a lot of time typing it into the editor.

--------> Here starts the problem <------

During the import process I need to insert the data imported in a specific point of the document and this point is where the cursor is pointed on Primefaces editor. Which means, it can be anywhere!

Well, here is what I thought and what I have done until now:

1 - Retrieve data and create a formated String - ok (Java)
2 - Get the cursor position inside the dialog - I think it is ok (JavaScript)
3 - Put the String from data imported - Not so great (JavaScript)

My plan was to get the cursor position then use substring to break the text into two parts, then I would put the data imported in the end of the first 
part and finally merge with the second part.

The main problem is that when I get the cursor position it is based on the processed text showed in the editor, I mean, just plain text. But when I get
the text from a variable in my Java ManagedBean or even in editorFrame.innerHTML the string is full of tags meta-data (e.x. `<span>`, `<br>` etc ), so the index to substring does not match and I end up importing in the wrong place.

Is there a better solution or some way to get over it?

here is how I get the cursor position and how I try to import the text:

```
function getCaretPosition() {
    var element = window.frames[0].document.body; // just my content IFRAME
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel, range, preCaretRange, caretOffset = 0;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } 
    else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = doc.selection.createRange();
        var tempRange = range.duplicate();
        preCaretRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", tempRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}

function doImport(){
    var importedText = "here is the text I want to import into the editor...";
    var caret = getCaretPosition();

    var editorFrame = window.frames[0].document.body;
    var textEditor = editorFrame.innerHTML;
    textEditor = textEditor.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");


    var initTxt = textEditor.substring(0, caret );
    var endTxt = textEditor.substring(caret , textEditor.length);


    editorFrame.innerHTML = initTxt + importedText + endTxt;

}
```

-------------EDITED BELOW-------

Here is some example of what occurs:

Consider the following text in the editor:

_____This is just a simple text I wrote trying to explain my problem.

Let's suppose I got a string "beautiful" set on a variable in my ManagedBean and I want to insert it between the words "simple" and "text", what I need to do is put the cursor between these words and click on a button.

the result I want is

_____This is just a simple **beautiful** text I wrote trying to explain my problem.

If I use the JavaScript function getCaretPosition() I posted before it would return me the index 27 between the words "simple" and "text". But if I try to do a subString in Java or JavaScript to put the "beautiful" word using 27 index it will get wrong and I will tell you why.

Think of the "_____" as a tab command, getCaretPosition() will consider it as char 0, the whole "_____". If I select the first letter "T" on the text getCaretPosition() will return 1 because it is its index, remember the whole "_____" is index 0. But in Java and JavaScript the String will be:

```
 \tThis is just a simple text I wrote trying to explain my problem.
  //now charAt 0 is \ and not a sequence of spaces, charAt 1 is t from the tab command not from the text beggining.

 <span class="Apple-tab-span" style="white-space:pre">  </span>This is just a simple text I wrote trying to explain my problem.
```

So, that is the problem, I cant get a cursor position that matchs the real String so that I could know the point I should insert the text!

If I use subString based on the index I get from JavaScript I get the wrong position in both Java and JavaScript. Using JavaScript is even less accurated because of a lot of tags, in Java it is just things like \t, \n.

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:java] tag. Please understand that Java and Javascript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : nope, looks like he passes sth from java to js

Comment: @Jonasw either that or the opposite. Or both directions? To be honest, I was a bit confused by the question after reading it a couple of times. There does seem to be Java involved at some point however, I'm not sure _if_ it's relevant to the question (looks a bit like the question is purely to do with JS) or _how_ (don't get what is the relevance of Java, even though it's apparently part of the wider application).

Comment: @Scrougge: your js looks like my java: messy. Youre reassigning the same values to vars in each function, simply make them global.

Comment: @Scrougge this question is not really clear, please debug it until you have ONE SINGLE PROBLEM. Than shortify/beautify your code, post it with a specific error, and we can help you

Comment: I thought it is related to Java too because 90% of the project is Java, we use Java script just for some actions and events we cannot do with Java/JSF/Primefaces, so if there is any way to get over it with Java it would be welcome too. I will edit the original post with more information